# Can SVG foreignObject s be HTML5

Tags: html, svg, xhtml

Must SVG foreignObject contain only XML? That seems to be my reading of the spec, so is it required to put XHTML inside, if I wish to use foreignObject? Or can I just copy my regular HTML5 syntaxed code inside?

Comment: @Kaiido I was worried that the HTML5 does not have a namespace, since it is technically not XML, perhaps the XML parser might be used and choke or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of any document must reflect the mime type it's served as.

- If you serve the document as image/svg+xml then the whole document must be valid XML including any foreignObject child elements which basically limits you to XHTML. XML fails on error so if you paste in HTML you'll likely just get a syntax error printed than have anything rendered.
- If you serve the document as text/html then the whole document is HTML and any SVG in it would be parsed with an HTML parser, no namespaces required etc. Any foreignObject elements in such SVG will be parsed as if they were standard HTML. HTML attempts to render what it can of invalid documents.

Comment: I found this a while ago though https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas. In the "Drawing HTML" section, it seems to indicate that the contents must in fact be valid XML? (I solved my original problem already, so this is just for intellectual curiosity)

Comment: That article does it the way of the first bullet point in my answer.